# Copy multiple rows of data to another table and update the copied rows in the old table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

need help on copying while updating multiple rows of data from one table to another table.

After copying and inserting those data from the old table to the new table, i would like to update the old table rows that was copied.

For example, OldTable has 30 rows of data. I want to copy 10 rows of data to NewTable and I want to update the column of the 10 rows in the OldTable to 'Copied'.

Question would be how does the old table know which rows had been copied to the new table so that I could update it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [OUTPUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause:

```
update top(10) OldTable
set column = 'Copied'
output deleted.fields into NewTable.fields
where condition;
```

Comment: thanks. the fields are table columns right? If I were to copy all columns to the new table how do I work around it?

Comment: it's ok found the workaround output deleted.* into Newtable. Thanks a bunch!